# URLSession datatask accessing older version of website?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am using URLSession to scrape JSON data from my website. My code was throwing various errors relating to casting types, so I added some print statements to my code and found that this function is for some reason accessing an older version of my site. I have since updated the website's data, and verified that the new data is displaying properly both through visiting the website myself and using Rested. However, the print statements in the code below yield old data. The code does not read data from the disk so I am not sure why this is happening.

I have removed the website's link from my code for privacy purposes, but otherwise the function can be found below.

```
   func websiteToDisk() {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        config.waitsForConnectivity = true

        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let url = URL(string: someURL)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in

            do {

                print("Getting information from website")

                if let error = error {

                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                } else if let data = data,

                    let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,

                    response.statusCode == 200 {

                    //do {

                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

                    print("about to dcode")

                    let decodedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]//try jsonDecoder.decode([String: [String]].self, from: data)

                    print(decodedData)

                    print("accessing dictionary")

                    print(decodedData!["busLoops"])

                    let toWrite = decodedData!["busLoops"] as! [String]



                    let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

                    let busLoopsURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("busLoops").appendingPathExtension("json")



                    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()

                    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(toWrite)

                    try jsonData.write(to: busLoopsURL)

                    //} catch { print(error)}

                }

            }

            catch { print(error)}

        }

        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to extrapolate

Comment: "How to extrapolate"? What does that mean? Extrapolate what, from what? Be specific, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ignore local cache data

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://....") else{
    return
}
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, resp, error) in

}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much.